# Align fixed navigation-div to the right outer div

Tags: html, css

The navigation bar sticks to the left of the container-div. But I want it to stick to the right. I tried several things but none of them worked. So here is the barebones code. 
How can I get a navigation bar that sticks to the right side, ending exactly where my container-div ends?

PS: It has to be fixed because I want the navigation to stay at the top of the browser window, no matter how much the user scrolls down.

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 820px;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put your code in a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what's going on? I could take a wild guess at adding `right:0` to the navigation CSS, but I'd like to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had a guess at your HTML code and build up this for you: [**`http://jsfiddle.net/vdL6b/`**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdL6b/)

From what I can imagine you're trying to achieve, it's possible with one of two solutions:

1. Removing `position:fixed;` and adding `float: right;` to your navigation CSS.
2. Adding `right: 0;` to define the position.

I chose the latter. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMcNaught/vdL6b/1/) using the first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2KzSN/4/ I did it with margin-left:380px; but it isnt considered as a real solution by others.

Comment: That's not a real solution. Even though you're using a defined width container, my resolution is 2560x1440 and `margin-left: 380px;` leaves a small 5px gap between the right edge. Your margin works for your screen resolution and browser zoom, but might not for anybody else, which is why you want to stick it to the right, rather than forcing it with a margin.

Plus, if you ever wanted to turn responsive, you'd have a real issue with `margin-left` as you'd be guessing their browser-size. It's much more practical to stick it using `right: 0;` as the purpose of this property is positioning.

Comment: If I use right 0; it sticks to the right side of the browser, but not to the right side of the container-div

Comment: I've build this up from absolute scratch for you. Hopefully this is your solution and we can close this question. http://jsfiddle.net/r8Q7M/

Comment: That color code lol. Thank you very much. I will compare your code and mine and search for the things I am missing. THANKS!